# Servicio Spring devuelve un resultado vacio si el resultado es muy grande

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

estoy trabajando en un servicio Spring que obtiene datos desde BBDD y devuelve un JSON con una lista de objetos.

Este servicio devuelve TODOS los registros que tenemos en una tabla especifica. En total unos 10000 registros mas o menos.

El metodo de obtencion de datos es rapida usando Threads, pero a la hora de que el servicio devuelva los resultados de la peticion es cuando es lento.

Además cuando el tamaño del json sobrepasa los 700 registros obtenemos un resultado vacío. Cada objeto de la lista tiene unos  70 campos

¿Alguien sabe algun metodo para que Spring no tarde tanto en devolver los resultados?

¿Hay algun limite de tamaño de respuesta para un servicio Spring?

Aqui os dejo el codigo:

```
public String getData(final Pageable pageable) throws Exception {
        
        final int numberOfThreads = 10;

        final StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.append("{" + "\"content\": [");

        // Here we are obtaining all the data in diferents treads and appending in variable String 
         strContent 
        
        String strContent = getDataByThreads(numberOfThreads);
        // Here strContent contains 10.000 or more objects in JSON format


        logger.info(" -------------- END OF {} THREADS  ----------------- ", numberOfThreads);

        final long totalPages = (totalCount / fetchSize) + 1;
        final boolean last = Math.ceil(totalPages) == pageable.getPageNumber();
        final boolean first = pageable.getPageNumber() == 0;

        // Mounting the response JSON
        str.append(strContent);
        str.append("],");
        str.append("\"last\": " + last + ",");
        str.append("\"totalElements\": " + totalCount + ",");
        str.append("\"totalPages\": " + totalPages + ",");
        str.append("\"first\": " + first + ",");
        str.append("\"numberOfElements\": " + fetchSize + ",");
        str.append("\"size\": " + fetchSize + ",");
        str.append("\"number\": " + pageable.getPageNumber());
        str.append("}");

        // Here is where Spring takes a long time...
        return str.toString();
    }
```

Como podeis ver devolvemos un JSON en formato String porque los objetos tienen campos dinamicos y no son fijos

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Faltan líneas de código en ese método, ya que hay varias variables que no veo declaradas. Por otro lado, si tienes una lista de  Map<String, Object>, Spring es capaz de serializarla a JSON automáticamente de un modo bastante eficiente. Quizá estás reinventando la rueda en este caso

Answer (score 0):

Con un problema parecido la única manera que encontré para elementos tan grandes (en mi caso varios GB) fue crear un fichero y servirlo

```java
@GetMapping
public StreamingResponseBody csvResult(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception  {
      File file = generateFile();
      response.setContentType("text/csv");
      response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=\"data.csv\"");
        return outputStream -> {
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            InputStream inputStream =  new FileInputStream(file);
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        };
}
```

En cualquier caso, creo que podrías implementar eso con las páginas de spring directamente y probablemente sea más eficiente en la serialización, en cuyo caso podrías configurar el máxima de elementos, que por defecto es de 1000

```
spring.data.rest.max-page-size=2147483647
```